# How do I install pulseaudio 10 on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

The latest version I have is PulseAudio 5.0, while the newest version is PulseAudio 10.0 How do I install pulseaudio 10.0 on the Raspberry Pi 3 running on Raspbian Jessie?

Comment: `apt list pulseaudio` shows that it's the latest in the repository, you should just have to update